# How to disable or enable join table or onetomany relation in the jpa entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to disable or enable the entity relation (@oneToMany) for fetching the join table query.
I knew that we can disable or enable the filters (@FilterJoinTable) in the entity using entity manager. Likewise can we do for entity relational tables ?.
For More precisely I want to stop or start fetching or selecting the child table result.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Vehicle{
//@Filter i.e enable or disable
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicle")
Set<Car> cars;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 1) why do you want to do that? 2) show some code what you tried so far

Comment: Because the REST API doesn't require the child records and also it has more number of records.In order to improve the performance of the API, I need to remove to disable and enable when it require.      
I will update the question with sample code.

Comment: So you don't want to enable or disable anything. You want to write the appropriate queries that fetch or don't fetch the association depending on the use-case. The hibernate documentation explains how to fetch associations in queries.

Comment: what you mean...I don't want to write separate model for that. so is there no other way to do it apart from @Filters or you mean by having such methods and can you give sample code for it.

Comment: I mean exactly what I meant. Don't use filters. Don't use a separate model. Use the appropriate code and queries that fetch the association if you need to fetch it, or don't fetch the association if you don't need to fetch it. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join. Different use cases need different code, but these two use cases use the same, unique persistence model.

Comment: @Override
public List<?> getAllVehicle() {
 Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select v from Vehicle v", Vehicle.class);
 return query.getResultList();
 
}               
The above method returns Car result also but i need only vehicle result.

Comment: No, it doesn't return cars. You, or your JSON or XML serializers, iterate through the collection of cars after executing the query, and that it what it loading the cars.

Comment: Hibernate: select vehicle0_.id as id1_11_, vehicle0_.stage_id as stage_id2_11_, vehicle0_.type as type3_11_ from vehicle vehicle0_
Hibernate: select cars0_.vehicle_id as vehicle_3_5_0_, cars0_.id as id1_5_0_, cars0_.id as id1_5_1_, cars0_.model as model2_5_1_, cars0_.vehicle_id as vehicle_3_5_1_ from car cars0_ where cars0_.vehicle_id=?


Hibernate logs are showing both queries excecuting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195075/discussion-between-sandy-and-jb-nizet).